# Execute pytest from another python script within docker

Tags: python, docker, pytest, python-docker

I have a test script written using pytest and it works fine when I execute it as standalone.

`User:~my_workspace/python_project$ pytest path_to_script/my_script.py`

Now I have to run this script with different parameters and hence I have created a python file **(script_to_invoke_pytest.py)** so that I can run the pytest script from this python file.

I tried below approaches within my **script_to_invoke_pytest.py**

```
#approach 1
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['pytest', r'path_to_script/my_script.py'], shell=True)
```

```
#approach 2
import pytest
pytest.main([r'path_to_script/my_script.py'])
```

Both the approaches didn't work and I get errors related no modules named xyz.

Im using pycharm ide and before running pytest, I execute the docker.

Please let me know how can I invoke my pytest from my python script script_to_invoke_pytest.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second approach, you're not telling python where to find the tests. Try:

```
import pytest
pytest.main([r'path_to_script/my_script.py'])
```

Comment: Sorry , I updated my second approach. I tried it , but I get Import errors such as no module named XYZ and so on. These modules loads and works fine , when I run the pytest as standalone.

Comment: Thanks. After I placed the script_to_invoke_pytest.py in the same folder of the pytest script. The solution worked.